# How do I use a makefile with a wildcard to generate files within all subdirectories?

Tags: makefile

I have the following directory structure:

```
superfolder
    makefile
    subfolder1
        file.tex
    subfolder2
        file.tex
    ...
    subfolderN
        file.tex
```

This is my current `superfolder/makefile`:

```
file.pdf : file.tex
    pdftex file.tex
```

If my current working directory is, for example, `superfolder/subfolder1` I can create `superfolder/subfolder1/file.pdf` by using `make --file ../makefile`.

Suppose my current working directory was `superfolder`. How can I edit my makefile such that `make all` would create `file.pdf` in every subfolder?
(i.e. create `subfolder1/file.pdf`, `subfolder2/file.pdf`, ..., `subfolderN/file.pdf`)
If it makes things easier, you may assume that every subfolder invariably contains `file.tex`.

Comment: Ended up simply using a bash command:  

all :  
 find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "$$0" && make --file ../makefile' {} \;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
OUTPUTS := subfolder1/file.pdf
OUTPUTS += subfolder2/file.pdf
OUTPUTS += ...
OUTPUTS += subfolderN/file.pdf

all: $(OUTPUTS)

$(OUTPUTS): %.pdf: %.tex
    (cd $(dir $<) && pdftex $(notdir $<))

.PHONY: all
```

This way you can manage which files will be built by `make`. And, as it is using real file targets (not phony targets), `make` will rebuild only the needed files.

So you should be able to do `make` (or `make all`) in the `superfolder` directory to build all files. If you want to build only one `file`, do this:

```
make subfolderN/file
```

If you are in a `subfolder` directory you can rebuild the needed file this way:

```
make --file ../Makefile
```

Or to rebuild *only* the file in your directory:

```
make --file ../Makefile $(basename $(pwd))/file
```

**EDIT:** To automate the process, you can replace the first lines by:

```
OUTPUTS := $(patsubst %.tex,%.pdf,$(wildcard */file.tex))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was preferably looking for a method that would both rebuild only the needed files and would not force me to manually add each target to the makefile. I should have stated above that the number of subfolders in the `superfolder` directory will increase over time. I will accept this answer if nobody else responds with a more general/automated solution.

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar See my comment for the automated solution. I first believe that you want to manually manage each file to build

Comment: Wonderful! Now it must be fixed for folders with spaces. e.g. `superfolder/sub folder`

Comment: It also seems to generate the pdf files in the `superfolder` rather than the pertinent subfolder. Is this the case for you?

Comment: I changed the `pdftex $<` line to `cd $(<D) && pdftex details.tex` and now it produces the pdf file in the correct subdirectory. The only thing to fix is subfolders with a space in their name and your answer will be accepted. :)

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar I don't use the `pdftex` command, so I doesn't know that the produced files are in the current directory. I update the target rule to fit your changes. The spaces in Makefiles are really annoying. I advised you to rename your directories without spaces if possible.

Comment: Fallen at the final hurdle! I think you're right; judging by the GNU make tutorial and other answers on SO, any automated solution that will accept spaces in the subdirectory names will be extremely convoluted—if it is indeed possible. I suppose I'll stick to the original manual method for now.